# No output is coming out after I input two values

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't seem to get the season to appear when I input a month and a day via the Scanner entity. I have tried many diferent methods, though none of them seem to be working. The code is shown below.

```
public class Lab7Smalls {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    private int month = 0;
    private int day = 0;

    String season = "";
    String winter = "winter";
    String spring = "spring";
    String summer = "summer";
    String fall   = "fall";

    System.out.print("Enter a month: ");
    month = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a day: ");
    day = scan.nextInt();


    if (month < 0 || month > 12) System.out.println("Not correct");

    if(month <= 3){
        season = winter;
    } 
    else if(month <= 6){
        season = spring;
    }
    else if(month <= 9){
        season = summer;
    }
    else if(month <= 12){
        season = fall;
    }
    if(month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21){
        if(season.equals(winter)){
            season = spring;
        }
        else if(season.equals(spring)){
            season = summer;
        }
        else if(season.equals(summer)){
            season = fall;
        }
        else if(season.equals(winter)){
            season = winter;
        }
        System.out.println("Season: " + season);
        }
    }
}
```

The example for the output:

Enter a month: 1
Enter a day: 28

Comment: What's your problem (the code, not you:))? What's not working?

Comment: 1%3 != 0, therefore the Print statement is never called. Your condition "month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21" is not satisfied. Print the output outside of the if statements.

Comment: When I typed in the month & day, the season was supposed to be the output.

Comment: Check the if block where the print statement is in.

Comment: as you do if(month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21), when input month = 1, it will be false because 1%3=1.

Comment: What about the last print statement?

Comment: what do you expect to if(false)?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but this was a little long for a comment,

The `System.out.println` command is inside `if(month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21){....}` block, you have entered *1* for the month and as `1%3=1` so of course that *if* block will not executed and you will see nothing in output, you'll see something if and only if your input data meets the condition of if statement

Answer (score 0):

If the `month % 3 != 0` and the `day < 21`, nothing happens, because there is no `else` statement. Your code will only print the season if the `month % 3 == 0` and the `day >=21`. You have two options:

The easier option: Move `println` outside of the if statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int month;
        int day;
        String season = "";
        System.out.print("Enter a month: ");
        month = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter a day: ");
        day = scan.nextInt();

        String winter = "winter";
        String spring = "spring";
        String summer = "summer";
        String fall = "fall";

        if(month <= 3){
            season = winter;
        } 
        else if(month <= 6){
            season = spring;
        }
        else if(month <= 9){
            season = summer;
        }
        else if(month <= 12){
            season = fall;
        }
        if(month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21){
            if(season.equals(winter)){
                season = spring;
            }
            else if(season.equals(spring)){
                season = summer;
            }
            else if(season.equals(summer)){
                season = fall;
            }
            else if(season.equals(winter)){
                season = winter;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Season: " + season);
    }
```

Option two: Add an `else` statement. Don't know why you would want to do this, but I'll put it here anyways.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int month;
    int day;
    String season = "";
    System.out.print("Enter a month: ");
    month = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a day: ");
    day = scan.nextInt();

    String winter = "winter";
    String spring = "spring";
    String summer = "summer";
    String fall = "fall";

    if(month <= 3){
        season = winter;
    } 
    else if(month <= 6){
        season = spring;
    }
    else if(month <= 9){
        season = summer;
    }
    else if(month <= 12){
        season = fall;
    }
    if(month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21){
        if(season.equals(winter)){
            season = spring;
        }
        else if(season.equals(spring)){
            season = summer;
        }
        else if(season.equals(summer)){
            season = fall;
        }
        else if(season.equals(winter)){
            season = winter;
        }
        System.out.println("Season: " + season);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Season: " + season);
    }
}
```